# What is the advantage of making logic to manage the network by injecting dependency using context API in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-context

```
export class HttpClientService {
  private baseURL: string;
  tokenRepository: LocalTokenRepository;
  instance: AxiosInstance;

  constructor(baseURL: string, tokenRepository: LocalTokenRepository) {
    this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    this.baseURL = baseURL;
    this.instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: this.baseURL,
      headers: { Authorization: this.tokenRepository.get() }
    });

    this.handleInterceptor();
  }
  private handleInterceptor = () => {
    this.instance.interceptors.response.use(
      this.handleResponse,
      this.handleError
    );
  };

  private handleResponse = ({ data }: AxiosResponse) => data;

  protected handleError = (error: any) => Promise.reject(error);
}
```

```
export class AuthService {
  private httpClient: HttpClientService;
  private tokenRepository: LocalTokenRepository;
  constructor(
    httpClient: HttpClientService
    // tokenRepository: LocalTokenRepository
  ) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
    this.tokenRepository = this.httpClient.tokenRepository; 
  }

  async signup(email: string, password: string) {
    const accessTOKEN = (await this.httpClient.instance.post(
      'data',
      { email, password },
      { params: '' }
    )) as string;
    this.tokenRepository.save(accessTOKEN);
  }

  async singin(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log(email, password, 'signIn?');
    // return await this.httpClient.instance.get('products', { params: '' });
  }

  signout() {
    this.tokenRepository.remove();
  }
}
```

```
export const apiContext = createContext<APIType | null>(null);

const tokenRepository = new LocalTokenRepository();
const httpClient = new HttpClientService('baseurl', tokenRepository);
const productService = new ProductService(httpClient);
const authService = new AuthService(httpClient);

export const ApiProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <apiContext.Provider value={{ productService, authService }}>
      {children}
    </apiContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I made network logic like this. Make the network logic by class and inject dependency by context API. Is there any advantages of making network logic by class?
I don't recognize between network class logic and use axios right away.

What is the best way to handle api logic in react? and What kind of method people use the most?